# How to keep project libraries withint the project structure?

Tags: android, android-library

I'm using `ActionBarSherlock` project as a Library in my project. I want to keep it in version control system but I can't store it within project's folder structure for some reason. I tried to move Library's folder to `my_project/libs/` folder but then things just do not compile. Does it mean it is prohibited to keep "Projects as Libraries" within your project folder? If it is not - how to make things work?

Comment: No, Its not prohibited in fact its suggested that you keep jars in /libs folder.  You should figure out why is it giving compilation errors.

Comment: Not jars, but 'project as library'.

Comment: Yes, you can do this. Put the project files into /libs, import the project into eclipse and link the library project to your main project.
Any further errors are likely compilation errors. Post the errors you are getting if so.

I do this myself and keep the whole project and libs under source control.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to put ABS inside your project, you could put both projects inside a parent directory.

Here's an [example](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/).

Notice how the ABS library project is in `gi/libprojects/abs` and the android app project is in `git/android`.

Comment: This way I'll lose all my commits history, is there any way to keep it?

Comment: Which vcs are you using? In subversion you can use the move command and keep all history `svn move source destination`.

Answer (score 0):

Did I understood you correctly, you want the ABS Lib to be in your Libs folder *inside* your project?

Why? For that you would have to rename all the packagenames of the ABS project and the manifest. I'm not even sure if this will even work. If ABS would be a .jar file it would be easy. But an Android project inside an other project... I would't reccommend you doing this.